# Why was this question closed?

Tags: support, status-completed, closed-questions, reopen-request

Why was [this question on Windows documentation](https://superuser.com/questions/263120/what-kinds-of-windows-documentation-for-sysadmins-are-available-closed) closed? It is based on an actual problem I faced, it is answerable and it is about software.  The reason given to close it, being outside the scope defined in the faq just does not hold.  Why did nobody of those who voted to close it leave a comment?

Comment: the question seems more like is there a website for documentation than anything

Comment: They should mention this in the faq: Never let your post appear it has anything to do with websites.  Maybe one should always add a disclaimer like "This post is not related to websites.  If you're interested in what it is actually related to, please read the post."

Comment: `and it is not about …` **websites or web services** - says the [FAQ](http://superuser.com/faq)

Comment: I've even explicitly asked for command line accessible documentation.  It is clearly not a question about websites.  ... If you're interested in what it is *actually* related to, please read the post.

Comment: @Sathya Yes it says posts mustn't be related to websites or web services.  But it does not say posts also mustn't *appear* to be so.  (Note the difference between appearing and actually being.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've reopened the question. As I commented, I recall the post being more of a question of which websites I can get the documentation from. That seems to be an incorrect assumption, and some of the community members seem to agree with the same.